# Does the +2 (or+4) for Striking Looks apply to an Awe roll?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

When making a roll on Majesty to Awe people, is a Vampire permitted to make use of the +2 (or +4) social bonus for the merit of being exceptionally attractive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

Unless explicitly forbidden, Merits (like Striking Looks) do apply to Discipline rolls.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone with the rule of thumb that effects can be stacked unless the rules explicitly say they don't. I don't see anything in the rules saying they don't. Logically it makes sense that beauty would play a role in successfully Awing someone. If I were running the game, I'd allow it.

Comment: Agreed.  With a touch of common sense.  Striking Looks probably shouldn't help intimidate someone, for example.  Unless the player has specifically used their looks to get the target to lower defences first, in which case they have role-played themselves back into an advantage,

Answer (score 0):

Striking Looks explicitly does add to Majesty rolls, as I recall.

It's also a +1/+2 bonus, not a +2/+4.